# Firefox fetch refuses to send custom headers

Tags: firefox

Googled for an hour, but cannot find any hints to what I'm missing here.

[This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hd5y8guL/) works fine in Chrome, but Firefox is not even trying to send the OPTIONS request.

```
fetch("http://localhost:8080/mutate?commitNow=true", {
  method: "POST",
  body: '{"set": { "name": "Alice" }}',
  //headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
  headers: [ ["Content-Type", "application/json"] ]
})
```

There's no network request fired in firefox de tools and I've confirmed that the server does not receive any requests.
In Chrome same fiddle does send preflight and the request.
If I comment out the custom headers it starts to work fine in Firefox too. But I need to set content-type.

**How do I make Firefox send custom headers with CORS fetch?**

Error message in console is:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/mutate?commitNow=true. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
```

This message isn't helpful because request wasn't even attempted (see above)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Firefox silently blocks requests from https:// to http://

After I changed the code to use `fetch("https://localhost:8080`, I see the OPTIONS request, as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type" in your server response